# Google static map api is getting error "error/billing"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google static map api in my project. Sometime is displays the map i.e 2 to 3 times a day but mostly it displays

[image]

I have go through https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/error-messages for possible errors and their solutions but I cant find any thing related to this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to generate a new key and use it. Please share any useful information from your JS console after generating/using the new key. Confirm you are not located in a [prohibited territory](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-prohibited-territories/). **And** share your code so we can see how you are trying to load it.

Comment: You are receiving the error because you haven't enabled your billing yet, kindly enable your billing in order to continue using the API. 

You won't have extra charges unless you upgrade your billing account.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the API key for Google maps. You need to generate an API key from Google developer console.

Comment: I have the api key generated for the static-map-api and I am sending it with each api call.

Comment: its getting error 403, and when i open the error link in browser it displays the error image as in m question.

Comment: Is there any useful information in the javascript console?

Comment: No its only displaying the error 403 and displaying this error image

Comment: @NomanFareed are you using the latest version of google maps? and I think someone or maybe you are accidentally DOSing your google maps api request. To verify this problem, try and generate new API key and include it in your website.

Comment: Did you also enable Billing for your API key? Billing is mandatory now.

Comment: Having the same error here. Sending only Key works for 1 call and then it asks for signature. Sending key + signature works for 1 call and then billing error keeps coming. I have billing enabled and have regenerated key and secret several times.